# Extracting data from SharePoint list

Tags: list, survey-list, survey

I want to extract SharePoint list data to SharePoint to external sources (XML, database, ...) through programs in which you can analyze that information. The elements of the list in my case are survey responses SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract Survey Answers:

```
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
webURL: "http://sharepointsite/",
listName: "SurveyMobileSP",
CAMLQuery:"",
error: function (xhr, message, error) {
    alert('Error : ' + error);
},
completefunc: function (xData, status) {
    console.log('Status: '+status+' xdata: ' + 'RESPONSE: ' + xData.responseText);
});
});
```

To extract Survey Questions

```
function getSurveyQuestions(complete) 
{
  $().SPServices({
operation: "GetList",
listName: "Survey",
completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
  var questions = []; 
  $(xData.responseXML).find("Fields > Field[SourceID!='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3']").each(function() {
    var $fieldNode = $(this).get(0);
    questions.push($fieldNode);
  });
  complete(questions);
}
  });
}
```

To Get Usage:

```
getSurveyQuestions(
  function(questions)
  {
 for(var i = 0; i < questions.length;i++) {
    console.log( "Question: " + $(questions[i]).attr("DisplayName"));         
 }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this only be done from JavaScript / jQuery, you can not do from most languages? And for issues of authentication before data extraction how it might be controlled?

Comment: Authentication will be as per Current Logged in User. User having view access to list should be able to get data from the List using above script.

Also you can use Server side model or Client side model of C# to get items from the List.